# How to put CheckBoxPreference on pop out dialog like ListPreference

Tags: android, usability, listpreference, checkboxpreference

I have several preferences items that a user can choose from and wanted to have them on a CheckBoxPreference widget. Since its a list of over 7 Items; on a preference activity with other options, it may lead to an unsightly scrolling IMHO. So I wanted to have it like the ListPreference pop out which is built into it, how could I have that pop out for CheckBoxPreference? Thanks guys